# How can get the url code for next and previous posts in blogger

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I want to place manually the next and previous posts navigation. So for that I need the url of next and previous posts.

<`<a href="#"> </a>`>`

What code should I use in above anchor tab to point next or previous post.

Comment: What blogger? Why don't you just copy and paste the urls for the next and previous posts?

Comment: I want a general expression. This will make my work lot easier.

Comment: Once again, what blogger? If they use id's for their posts, why not just add and subtract one from the current URL

Comment: I have a blog in Google blogspot. Please share how can I subtract from current url.

Answer (score 0):

Search for this line in template: `<b:includable id='nextprev'>...</b:includable>`. All the necessary code are inside this includable.

Next link: `<a expr:href='data:newerPageUrl'><data:newerPageTitle/></a>`
Previous link: `<a expr:href='data:olderPageUrl'><data:olderPageTitle/></a>`
Link to full version of blog (from mobile template): `<a expr:href='data:desktopLinkUrl'><data:desktopLinkMsg/></a>`